# Does the fifth dot in an attribute or a skill cost two dots to purchase?

Tags: character-creation, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

In the older editions of World of Darkness, I remember a line during character creation stating that *"The fifth dot in any Attribute costs two dots to purchase."*

Is this the case in the Chronicles of Darkness?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No,
it is no longer the case in Chronicles of Darkness.

From the [FAQ:](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/816385-official-chronicles-of-darkness-resources-faq-animal-stats-condition-and-power-cards)

> **In first edition, purchasing the fifth dot of a trait at character creation cost two dots. Is this still true?**
>   No.

Note: the actual FAQ is listed [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13LTmz6TO4XqM9s-lg4XChwFAmFLEb96sFnjCzvMt61M/edit#heading=h.p0faomchu4xb)